# Going from projective measurement to unitiary operators for qiskit

Tags: qiskit, measurement

I have a solution to the Peres-Mermin magic squares game ([Wikipedia quantum pseudo-telepathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_pseudo-telepathy))

I simulate the six measurements using projective (non-unitary) measurement operators like in Nielson and Chuang's equation 2.94. I apply each of the $M_m$ to the state vector to generate a move by a player. The move, $\pm 1$, is the eignevalue.

Anyway, I want to port my solutin to qiskit so that I can run it on a real quantum computer. However, I am faced with a conceptual or mathematical difficulty. My measurement projection operators are not unitary but, I believe, in qiskit you simulate a measurement in a basis other than the computational basis using a unitary matrix. My matrices are not unitary.

How do you go from a projective measurement operator to a unitary transformation that reproduces the measurment?

Answer (score 1):

The unitary operator for a measurement that has outcomes $|a0\rangle$, $|a1\rangle$, $|b0\rangle$ and $|b1\rangle$, is constructed as the transformation that maps these eigenstates to the computatitonal basis:
$$
|00\rangle\langle a0|+|01\rangle\langle a1|+|10\rangle\langle b0|+|11\rangle\langle b1|
$$
That enables me to compute state vectors, in Qiskit, that match my calculations. However, the measurement counts still aren't right - they correspond to illegal moves in the game :-(

To recover the state after the mesurement, you apply the inverse transformation (adjoint).